# SPSS modeler v18: Can't use Googlemaps Node - Error: Execution was interrupted

Tags: gis, geocoding, esri

I tried geocoding in Modeler v18 and therefore I installed the ESRI-geocoding extension from the Hub, which was possible just after updating to v18.1.

However now, whenever I try to use any of these nodes - ReverseGeocodingESRI, GeocodingESRI, GoogleMaps, Heatmaps, I get the error I wrote in the title.

Is there anything I can do? I'm using the Student Version of this program.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when trying to map a generated prediction from an auto-classifier node. To get around it I just reclassified into a new variable and it worked fine for me!